# I need to switch to numbers-only keypad input on mobile after 6 letters

Tags: forms, input, text, numbers, keypad

I need to create a field where customers, on mobile, enter their "codice fiscale" (tax code). The code has this structure: (L=letter N=number)

LLLLLLNNLNNLNNNL

So basically what i'm trying to achieve is to automatically switch the user's keypad to numbers only when the next character has to be a number (on positions 7,8,10,11,13,14 and 15). I've seen it in some apps, but i can't figure out any way to do it.

Thanks for your help!

[Screenshot to explain better what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQpm4.png)